# Removing elements from a Hashmap

Tags: java, date, hashmap

Remove elements from a HashMap

I need to add 10 elements to a HashMap; name and DOB.

The removeAllSummerPeople should remove all those born in June, July, or August.

Very unclear what needs to be done.

```
    public static HashMap<String, Date> createMap() throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        HashMap<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
        map.put("Stallone", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));

        //write your code here
        map.put("a", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("b", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("c", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("d", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("e", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("f", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("g", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("h", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("i", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));


        return map;

    }

    public static void removeAllSummerPeople(HashMap<String, Date> map) {
        //write your code here
        for(HashMap.Entry<String, Date> pair : map.entrySet()){
            int x = pair.getValue().getMonth();
            if (x>=6 && x<=8){
                map.remove(pair.getKey());
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: I think it's clear what needs to be done, what's unclear is what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, getMonth is zero-based. meaning January is zero and December is 11. second of all you can not remove from map when you using foreach. you have to change your code to be like this:

```
public class BirthdayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        BirthdayTest b = new BirthdayTest();
        Map map = createMap();
        removeAllSummerPeople(map);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Date> createMap() throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        HashMap<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
        map.put("Stallone", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));

        //write your code here
        map.put("a", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("b", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("c", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("d", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("e", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("f", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("g", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("h", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("i", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));

        return map;

    }

    public static void removeAllSummerPeople(Map<String, Date> map) {
        Set<String> tobeDeleted = new HashSet<>();
        //write your code here
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Date> pair : map.entrySet()) {
            int x = pair.getValue().getMonth() + 1;
            if (x >= 6 && x <= 8) {
                tobeDeleted.add(pair.getKey());
            }
        }
        for (String str : tobeDeleted)
            map.remove(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have committed a primary error trying to remove a key from the object map that you are iterating. You must to create a copy first for the object map you want to remove and than iterate over the copy. for the date stuff put it in a String variable and check if contains the month you are looking for and delete it. No need to change anything on the method signature date.